# Shed some light on this Nvidia Pascal slide?

Tags: hardware, nvidia

What are the meanings of all the terms in this slide? Why is the correct operator to roughly compute (guesstimate) the improvement in performance multiplictive and not instead bottle necked by the new weakest link?

[image]

Comment: I think [the answers you're looking for are in this article](http://wccftech.com/nvidia-pascal-gpu-gtc-2015/). In particular, it points out that the "10x faster" is "CEO math," and that real-world workloads will see less improvement.

Comment: @DMGregory But why is it supposedly multiplicative i.e (a * b) vs.  min(a, b)?

Comment: Because it's hand-wavy "CEO math" and isn't a real measure of performance. I wouldn't try to read that slide as a literal claim of multiplicative performance scaling.

Comment: @DMGregory Makes sense. Would be strange if there was a huge boost.